# Forwarding an incoming call Twilio to multiple numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio, twilio-api

I have a application where I forward a call to a number using Twilio number as below,

```
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_sid, twilio_token
@call = @client.account.calls.create(
  from: twilio_number,
  to: to_number,
  method: 'GET',
  url:  "http://some_url",
  :status_callback => "http://some_url/webhook-callback",
  :status_callback_method => 'POST',
  :status_callback_event => ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed']
)
```

The `"url:http://some_url"` generates [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) for call forwarding like,

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
 <Response>
 <Pause length=\"10\"></Pause>
 <Play digits=\"#{from_number}#wwwwwwww1234#wwwwwww*72#wwwwww1#wwwwww#{to_number}#1#wwwwww\"></Play>
</Response>
```

So now I want to use another Twilio number instead of "to_number" and then  forward the call to multiple numbers.

What I am doing now, 
1. Use Twilio number to call a RACF number.
2. Provide TwiML to forward call from Phone1 to Phone2.

What I want to do,
1. Use Twilio number to call a RACF number.
2. Provide TwiML to forward call from Phone1 to second twilio number.
3. Forward incoming call to second twilio number to multiple number.

Comment: What's an RACF number?

Comment: Its the customer care or call center number of service provider for phone number.